# Get Content of ng-file-upload POST DATA

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, http

I am using `ng-file-upload` from [Github](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload). I have successfully uploaded and added image on both target folder and database. However, I need a specific data from my client side that will be needed for my query.

**Controller.js** ---- sample snippet of my upload function.

```
$scope.upload = function (dataUrl, name) {
        Upload.upload({
            url: 'php/profile-pic.php',
            method: 'POST',
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined,
                'Process-Data' : false
            },
            data: {
                file: Upload.dataUrltoBlob(dataUrl, name),
                id: user[0].id
            },

        }).then(function (response) {

            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.result = response.data;
            });
            console.log(response);
        }, function (response) {
            if (response.status > 0) $scope.errorMsg = response.status 
                + ': ' + response.data;

                console.log(response);
        }, function (evt) {
            $scope.progress = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        });
    }
```

**PHP** ---- relative code on my server side

```
        $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $data = json_decode($postdata);
        // $id = $data->id;
        echo json_encode($data) // returns null

        if(!empty($_FILES))  
        {  
            $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $destination = '/../images/' . $filename; 
             if(move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] , PATH . $destination ))  
             {  
                  $insertQuery = "UPDATE tblusers SET image = ".$_FILES['file']['name']." WHERE id='???'"; // ??? = the specific data that I need
```

**Image**  ---- from `console.log` `response`
[image: HTTP Response]
The `id` is what I need to get for my query.

How can I get that? `file_get_contents` not working for this one, it returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer I am looking for.

In my `upload function` in my `controller`, I changed the `key` `id` into `'id'` with apostrophe:

```
data: {
        file: Upload.dataUrltoBlob(dataUrl, name),
        'id': user[0].id
      }
```

In my `php code`, I did this:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

I got the idea from [Github Repo Issues](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/1884) at the last part of the page.